# Slide does not accept the width specified in the properties

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

Help, please, I can't understand what the problem is ...
Already tried everything that is possible and impossible, it still does not work :)
In the swiper settings (see screenshot) it is indicated that there should be one slide on the mobile phone, but for some reason there are all 24, how is it so incomprehensible
Those, You need to make sure that only one slide is shown from 420
The trick is that pagination tells us that one slide is displayed, but for some reason all are shown

**Screenshot of the problem** - https://ibb.co/0FQnvcV

**Screenshot with swiper settings** - https://ibb.co/tsMtN3G

I will be glad if you can help!!!

Comment: Please add minimal code example (Not screenshot) and live url. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @EzraSiton I don't know what code to give you.
To paint the whole section here seems to be nonsense.  
I uploaded the latest changes to the site, you can look there, it seems to me it will even be better (if that site is without SSL) - https://blanchard.sineylo-dev.ru/
Or the project repository - https://github.com/SineYlo/Blanchard